# De-compiling an APK

Tags: android, decompiler

:) Hi all. I've been following [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file) to decompile my own apk file. I'm using `APKTool` to decode the resources. But i've noticed that some of my files inside resources folder are missing. I'm not getting any errors/exceptions while using `APKTool`. Am i missing something here or is it just not possible to **completely** decompile an APK ?

All help appreciated!

Comment: did you enable proguard?

Comment: No i haven't enabled proguard.

Comment: In my experience it isn't possible to get your code back as it originally was. The apk will be translated back to code but there will be differences whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Try Android Suite.

AndroidSuite is a powerful tool that decode any type of apk and also encode resource files etc

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1461135

Answer (score 0):

I have just created and put online a service to decompile Android apk files to Java sourcecode: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

It is based on open-source apk decompiler called Jadx: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/
The service decompiles Android application without hassle.